# share folder between windows and linux without root permission

Tags: linux, samba

I have a development server which installed ubuntu and I just have normal permission in this server. I want to share a folder with Windows to store the code and compile the code in this server but edit them in Windows. How can I achieve this without root permission?

PS. it seems that samba is installed in that server

Comment: Just my opinion: Use a Version Control System like git or mercurial to share and access your code.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I miss some information i.e. the code is in another code server which use svn as version control tool. So, this approach seems not good for this situation.

Comment: Seems like the most common scenario to me: You edit code on your Windows machine, check-in to your svn repository and on your Linux machine pull from svn and build and deploy there. From what I gather you have very limited control over the Linux box so you are hitting a wall there because you cannot install and configure a build agent. If it's a matter of convincing people controlling the Linux box: Continuous Integration works well and will even allow better control over what is deployed to the target machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have an SSH server running on ubuntu, you can try installing e.g. [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) in windows and access ubuntu via `ssh`. If it works, you'll be able to use [`scp` to transfer data efficiently](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/)!

Another option is to use [`rsync` in combination with `ssh`](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/), which can be used from linux without root permission. However, you may have to adjust windows permissions, then.

Best solution, however, is using a version control system as @Filburt mentioned in a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo apt-get install samba libpam-smbpass`
2. `sudo service smbd restart`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`  ***and change the workgroup name*** -> workgroup = WORKGROUP
4. `sudo service smbd restart`
5. `sudo apt-get install winbind`
6. `sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf` ***add*** hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4
7. `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have root permission so sudo can't be executed by me